# How to set half expanded height for bottomsheet using BottomSheetScaffold in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-koin

I need to show my bottomsheet first in collapsed state. And on swipping bottomsheet up, it should first fix in half height of screen first. Again on swipping up , it should expand to max height of screen. Same during collapsing. First from max height to half height, then to peek height(the height of bottomsheet which will be visible in collapsed state). Is there any way to achieve it using BottomSheetScaffold?

Comment: let me guess, if I understand it correctly,  you want this to be implemented as a drag/swipe gesture right?, because this can be done just by using a button or some trigger outside, so I'm curious if those half~quarter close/open states should happen during swiping/dragging

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I started write that solution for you. You can beautify it

```
enum class ExpandedType {
    HALF, FULL, COLLAPSED
}

  @Composable
private fun BottomSheet() {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp
    var expandedType by remember {
        mutableStateOf(ExpandedType.COLLAPSED)
    }
    val height by animateIntAsState(
        when (expandedType) {
            ExpandedType.HALF -> screenHeight / 2
            ExpandedType.FULL -> screenHeight
            ExpandedType.COLLAPSED -> 70
        }
    )
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetElevation = 8.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(
            bottomStart = 0.dp,
            bottomEnd = 0.dp,
            topStart = 12.dp,
            topEnd = 12.dp
        ),
        sheetContent = {
            var isUpdated = false
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(height.dp)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectVerticalDragGestures(
                            onVerticalDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                change.consume()
                                if (!isUpdated) {
                                    expandedType = when {
                                        dragAmount < 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.COLLAPSED -> {
                                            ExpandedType.HALF
                                        }
                                        dragAmount < 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> {
                                            ExpandedType.FULL
                                        }
                                        dragAmount > 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.FULL -> {
                                            ExpandedType.HALF
                                        }
                                        dragAmount > 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> {
                                            ExpandedType.COLLAPSED
                                        }
                                        else -> {
                                            ExpandedType.FULL
                                        }
                                    }
                                    isUpdated = true
                                }
                            },
                            onDragEnd = {
                                isUpdated = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = height.dp
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. After customising , i am facing an issue. While collapsing my bottomsheet, its bottom end moving up . What will be the issue?

Comment: Simple fix is set .fillMaxSize() instead of .fillMaxWidth() above .pointerInput(Unit)

Comment: BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed) its showing unresolved as BottomSheetState can you please tell why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Found the way to fix issue about

> While collapsing my bottomsheet, its bottom end moving up

Based on accepted answer made some changes, and it seems to solve an issue

```
        val bottomSheetSt = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
            skipHiddenState = true,
            initialValue = SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded
        )
        val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetSt)
        var peekHeight: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }


        BottomSheetScaffold(
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                sheetContent = {
                    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                    BottomSheetGestureWrapper(
                        onExpandTypeChanged = {
                            scope.launch {
                                peekHeight = when (it) {
                                    ExpandedType.COLLAPSED -> 70
                                    ExpandedType.FULL -> screenHeight - 46
                                    ExpandedType.HALF -> screenHeight / 2
                                }
                                bottomSheetSt.partialExpand() // Smooth animation to desired height
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        // Bottom Sheet content
                    }
                },
                sheetPeekHeight = peekHeight.dp, // <------- Important 
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                sheetShadowElevation = 0.dp,
                sheetContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                sheetContentColor = Color.Transparent,
                sheetDragHandle = null,
            ) {
                // Scaffold content
            }
```

And also moved draggable staff to separate file

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetGestureWrapper(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onExpandTypeChanged: (ExpandedType) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    var expandedType by remember {
        mutableStateOf(ExpandedType.COLLAPSED)
    }

    var isUpdated = false

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = expandedType) {
        onExpandTypeChanged(expandedType)
    }

    Box(
        modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectVerticalDragGestures(
                    onVerticalDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consume()
                        if (!isUpdated) {
                            expandedType = when {
                                dragAmount < 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.COLLAPSED -> {
                                    ExpandedType.HALF
                                }

                                dragAmount < 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> {
                                    ExpandedType.FULL
                                }

                                dragAmount > 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.FULL -> {
                                    ExpandedType.HALF
                                }

                                dragAmount > 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> {
                                    ExpandedType.COLLAPSED
                                }

                                else -> {
                                    expandedType
                                }
                            }
                            isUpdated = true
                        }
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        isUpdated = false
                    }
                )
            }
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Comment: screenHeight what is this? can you provide this also?

Comment: @TanishqChawda check first answer.

```val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp```